# Remove share YouTube video that is embedded in a Google Form

Tags: video, youtube

Is possible to hide the sharing arrow on a YouTube video that is embedded in a Google Form? We have explored other avenues but no one seems to have a solution.

The share arrow is visible in the top right corner of the video if you hover your mouse over the clip.

We've been able to find code to add to youtube URL that will suppress the share arrow and suggested videos if we were to embed in a website (add "?wmode=opaque&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1") but Google Forms does not pick this up.

Is there a script that can be used in Google forms that will remove the video / sharing settings after the video has finished running?

Please help.. Thanks!
Anushka

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? If you're trying to totally obscure the source of the video, you can't really do that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Trying to hide / remove the share option on the video..

Comment: Yeah. Why are you trying to do that? What's the higher goal here?

Comment: Apologies, misunderstood the question. The video is part of an orientation that needs to be completed prior to starting an assignment. The goal of my project is to have the video accessible to a person outside the organisation so they can complete the orientation prior to starting their assignment. We want to prevent link sharing / hide the video as soon as its complete so the new hire will not be able to share it as we don't want the information to be public...

Comment: Right... you kinda can't really do that. The data that embeds it in the webpage can be shared further.

Comment: Thanks Benny! It was worth a try.